# Why HTML tag closing before loop automatically in PHP code

Tags: php, html, for-loop, tags

I am using PHP loop to display a list of values,
My code is something like this

```
if($v1 != $v2){
    $k= $k + 1;
    echo '<ul>';
}

echo '<li>xyz xyz</li>';
}

if($v1 != $v2){ 
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

It should display result like

```
<ul>
<li>xyz xyz</li>
<li>xyz xyz</li>
<li>xyz xyz</li>
</ul>
```

but is displaying result

```
<ul></ul>

<li>xyz xyz</li>
<li>xyz xyz</li>
<li>xyz xyz</li>

<ul></ul>
```

`</ul>` tag is automatically closing after first loop run, I am new at stackoverflow, hope you understand my issue.

Its my complete PHP code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $j = $i + 1;
    $v2 = $v1;
    $v1 = $data3['body']['asinVariationValues'][$i]['variationName'];
    $img = $data3['body']['asinVariationValues'][$i]['variationImageURL'];
    $val = $data3['body']['asinVariationValues'][$i]['variationValue'];
    
    if($v1 != $v2){
        $k= $k + 1;
        echo '<strong>'. $v1 .'</strong><ul id="j-sku-list-'.$k.'">';
    }

    if(!empty($img)){ 
        echo '<li><span title='.$val.'><img src='.$img.'></span></li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li><span title='.$val.'>'.$val.'</span></li>';
    }

    if($v1 != $v2){ 
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more code of the PHP? It seems like you have one too many closing parantheses on line 6.

Comment: I add my complete code in question

Comment: Your opening and closing `<ul>` should both be outside the loop, without the `if` statements. Open before the loop and close after.

Comment: what is $data3?

Comment: $data3 is a JSON array of data..

Comment: Your code is kinda hard to make sense of, could you tell us something more about what you're trying to do? For instance, I see if( $v1 != $v2)  but since you did not include any information, I have no idea what this is supposed to do. Furthermore, you set a variable called $j, but you don't seem to use it anywhere.

Comment: You should really start adding quotes around the attribute values in your HTML. Example: `<span title='.$val.'>`, if `$val` contains a string with spaces, it would generate: `<span title=foo bar>`.  The `title` would be set to `foo` and the `bar` would just be ignored by the browser as a "invalid attribute". If it contains a `>`, it would close the element. If you instead do: `<span title="'.$val.'">`, it would generate `<span title="foo bar">`, adding the complete string as the value.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Excellent, I do according to you, its working fine... You are great..

Answer (score 1):

Your check to show the opening ul tag is the same as your check to show the closing ul tag:    `$v1 != $v2`, so every time the opening tag shows the closing tag will show.

Can you change the opening tag check to:

```
    if($i == 0){
        $k= $k + 1;
        echo '<strong>'. $v1 .'</strong><ul id="j-sku-list-'.$k.'">';
    }
```

and the closing tag check to:

```
    if($j == $count){ 
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

This way the opening tag will only be added in the first loop, and the closing tag will only be added on the last run of the loop.